# Why are default values in python only evaluated one time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I define a default list parameter like so:

```
def foo(a, my_list=[]):
    my_list.append(a)
    return my_list
```

Then each successive call to foo() without passing the default parameter will append the element to this "hidden" list that seems to persist between calls.

```
print(foo('a'))
print(foo('b'))
print(foo('c'))
```

This prints:

```
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Why is this happening?  This seems like an antipattern.  To avoid this, I have to add the following trick:

```
def foo(a, my_list=None):
    if my_list is None:
        my_list = []
    my_list.append(a)
    return my_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually happens because, functions are actually objects.
take a look at this explanation it is very clear : http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm